# How to only sew a specific part of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I am trying to make an overcoat/trenchcoat type of mesh. At the bottom of the coat, there are two flaps that have to be drawn back to the sides. For reference, it is based on the French trenchcoats from during the Victorian era as shown [image: here]. So look at the bottom of the coat, notice how those flaps are attached with buttons on the side. I tried looking if I could do something with vertex groups and weight paint, but to no avail. 
Here is a [clip](https://youtu.be/L2cNMWbj4OI) I made of my issue. I am trying to use sewing in the cloth physics, but the physics are affecting my entire mesh, instead of just the bottom parts(the flaps more precisely). How would I go about this that only the bottom part is affected by the cloth physics and that the sew physics work only for the flaps?

Comment: so why didn't you succeed with vertex group and then use this group as Pinning so that only the bottom part moves? Also I'm not sure about the sewing thing, I guess it's only useful when your modeling your cloth, when you're glad with the sew you apply the Cloth modifier (then create a new one for the bottom flaps).

Comment: Well, The problem is I think that I just don't understand how it works. I've tried looking up some tutorials on cloth physics and weight paint and vertex groups. Most of them are still in 2.79 or earlier versions. I try to port and convert it, as it were, to 2.8, but I don' t think it seems to do what I want it to do.

Comment: you need to paint all the part of the mesh that you don't want to move, or select it and directly assign it to a group in the Vertex Group list, then in the Cloth panel > Pinning, choose this group so that Blender understands that it is supposed to stay still. The rest of the cloth will move. Have you already done that?

Comment: For some reason, what I did before with the vertex groups works now. When I did it yesterday, it did not work. I don't know what I did wrong last time...